# SQL Server 2014 CTP 2014 expiration date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I installed SQL Server 2014 CTP2 on a server and I have been testing the new features in SQL Server 2014. On the web site where I down loaded the software I notice the statement "expires on March 31, 2014". Can you explain what this means? Will we still be able to test SQL Server 2014 CTP2 after that date or does the SQL Server engine stop working?

Answer (score 2):

The service will not startup after the date mentioned.  Prior to that date, you will need to obtain the SQL Server 2014 RTM to continue using the product past the end of March.

This is a bit of conjecture on my behalf, but since Microsoft almost never releases a third community technology preview (CTP) edition of any product, they are highly likely to make the RTM version available to MSDN subscribers within the next week or two, and then to everyone shortly thereafter and certainly before the end of March.

Just announced; Microsoft has RTM'd SQL Server 2014 for GA on April 1st.  No joke.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Server Enginer or service will not stop after the date mentioned for trail version expiration date. You have to obtain the SQL Server 2014 RTM to continue using the product past the expiration date. I would suggest using SQL Server Express edition so that there is no expiration date.